# I need other syntax for RDLC Expression " =Fields!xxx.Value" where xxx contains dot(.)

Tags: rdlc, cls-compliant

I am generating report dynamically.

I have two tables User and Branch, and both have column name 'NAME'. So I use 'User.Name' and 'Branch.Name' as ColumnName in DataTable and bind it to RDLC using following code:

```
foreach(DataColumn dc in dtUser.Columns)
{
     rpt.ADDField("=Fields!"+dc.ColumnName"+".Value");
}
```

this gives an error that "Object Name must be CLS-complient identifiers". I think this is because the columnName contains dot(.).

Do we have any other syntax for this to be resolved?? (like =Fields![xxx.yyy].Value)